# Flatten joined DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I've joined some DStream's together, so that the current "datatype" of the DStream looks like this ( key and values):

```
DStream[(Long,((DateTime,Int),((Int,Double),Double)))]
```

But i want to get:

```
DStream[(Long,DateTime,Int,Int,Double,Double)]
```

or

```
DStream[(Long,(DateTime,Int,Int,Double,Double)]
```

is there any function which i could apply on my DStream to transform it or how could i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably looking for map function:

```
stream.map {case (lng, ((dt, i1),((i2, d1),d2))) => (lng,dt,i1,i2,d1,d2)}
```

or

```
stream.map {case (lng, ((dt, i1),((i2, d1),d2))) => (lng,(dt,i1,i2,d1,d2))}
```